# Javafx concurrency and gui-update

Tags: user-interface, asynchronous, javafx, task, overlay

What I'm trying to do is the following:
I want to fade in an overlay screen before doing some background work and fade the overlay screen out when the task finishes.

Anyhow, java performs the background task `requestService.doRequest` and afterwards it fades the screen in and out. So the current order is like:

- task
- fade in
- fade out

while it should be:

- fade in
- task
- fade out

I think I tried every possible configuration of Threads, Tasks, Service, etc..

So how do one correctly update the gui like I try to achieve?

*Controller.java*:

```
public void doRequest(Request r) {
    Task<Float> t = new Task<Float>() {

        @Override
        protected Float call() throws Exception {
            try {
                updateProgress(.5f, 1);
                requestService.doRequest(r);
            } catch(Exception e) {
                badge.setVisible(true);
                badge.setText(e.getMessage());
            } finally {
                updateProgress(0f, 1);
            }
            return null;
        }
    };

    overlay.opacityProperty().bind(t.progressProperty());
    overlay.opacityProperty().addListener((obs, o, n) -> System.out.println(n));
    t.run();

}
```

Btw: If I watch the update of the overlays opacityProperty, one can see that the property gets updated in the right order, but the gui refresh seems to hang.

Comment: You should do `new Thread(t).start();`, or execute the task on an `Executor`, instead of calling `t.run();`. What happens if you try that?

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I figured out the same solution as you suggested some time ago and forgot to post it. You are right. If i call `setExecutor` on the Service itself with a new Executor the service's tasks get executed in the background.